# python 3.6 displaying IndexError while using sys.argv

Tags: python-3.x, sys

## The code written

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
  print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
  account = sys.argv[1]
  sys.exit()
```

## The error being displayed

> IndexError: list index out of range

## Screenshot of the written code and displayed error

[image: Screenshot of the written code and displayed error:]

Comment: How are you calling the script?  `len(sys.argv) < 2` doesn’t guarantee `sys.argv[1]` exists.

Comment: Helpful tip, use the begins package, it makes working with command line arguments so much easier.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/begins/0.9

Answer (score 1):

Here you're checking for index to be less then 2, but using element with index 1 supposes the list length to be at least 2 - argv[0] and argv[1], which is not held here, so calling it by the index 1 triggers an error, as expected. So you have to do something like:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) <= 2 :
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')

    try:
        account = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        account = None
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(sys.argv)<2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()
account = sys.argv[1]
```

the above code works fine:
it checks for the presence of an argument
if present, it matches it with account name
if matched, it goes to the next lines {Line 23}
and copy the password from the present dictionary,{LIne 5}
else prints "not matched"

what was happening before was that it was finding an argument but assignment was performed for len(sys.argv)<2, thus due this being in the 2nd index there was an IndexError